# Parse website, find links to images and download png

Tags: java, jsoup, javax.imageio

My task is to parse website in order to find images in png format, download all of them and save on my computer.
My code is:

```
public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String html = "--url--";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();

    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");  
    for (Element link : links) 
    {
         System.out.println("link : " + link.attr("href"));
    }
```

From which I get results like: link : img0.png, link : img1.png, link : img2.png, which I guess is correct (?).
Then:

```
    String path = "C:/Users/me/Desktop/folder";
    for (Element link : links) 
    {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        File f = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(link.attr("href")));
            f = new File(path + link.attr("href") );
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    } 
}}
```

But it does not work. No errors, no files in folder.

Comment: 1. `new File(...)` assumes a file on your hard drive. You need to download the file first. 2. When the file is downloaded, you are basically done. There's no reason to involve `ImageIO` here, unless you want to manipulate the pixels in the image. Just store the file on your hard drive, like any other file.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File(link.attr("href")));
```

you are reading a file named `img0.png`, `img1.png`, ... from you hard drive, but you haven't saved them there.

You have to first download them using some Http client library.